# Choosing daily seasonal ARIMA model order vs. auto.arima

Tags: time-series, arima, seasonality, acf-pacf

I have the following `output_ts` that looks like this:

[image: output_ts]

When I run unit root tests, I receive the following output seeming to indicate that my series is trend stationary:

```
> adf.test(output_ts)

    Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test

data:  output_ts
Dickey-Fuller = -7.3922, Lag order = 14, p-value = 0.01
alternative hypothesis: stationary

Warning message:
In adf.test(output_ts) : p-value smaller than printed p-value
> kpss.test(output_ts, null = c("T"))

    KPSS Test for Trend Stationarity

data:  output_ts
KPSS Trend = 0.21269, Truncation lag parameter = 12, p-value = 0.01124

> nsdiffs(output_ts)
[1] 1
```

This seems to indicate that the suggested order of differencing is `d = 1`.  However, I also know that my data is daily and has a seasonality of `S = 7`.  This is confirmed by spectral decomposition of the time series frequency:

```
> findfrequency(output_ts)
[1] 7
```

`ACF` and `PACF` plots of `output_ts` look like this:
[image: ACF and PACF Plots]

Which seems to confirm that this time series has a seasonality of `S = 7`. Using the guidance given in this [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20151022014627/https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/node/67/).

I then applied a seasonal difference of `7` with the following results:

```
> output_diff7_ts = diff(output_ts, 7)
> plot(output_diff7_ts)
> acf2(output_diff7_ts)
```

[image: Diff output]

And `ACF` and `PACF` plots as follows:
[image: Diff7 ACF and PACF]

Based on the `PACF` plot and the spikes at lag 1, it seems like I need to add a non-seasonal AR(1) term. Based on the `PACF` plot and the spikes at lags 7, 14, 21, etc., it seems like I also need to add a seasonal MA(1) term.

So the final model should look something like: `ARIMA (1,0,0)(0,1,1)[7]` which I can fit using `Arima` from Prof. Hyndman's `forecast` package and check the residuals as follows:

```
> output_model = Arima(output_ts, order = c(1,0,0), seasonal=list(order=c(0,1,1),period=7))
> checkresiduals(output_model)
```

Which gives me the following:
[image: arima model]

```
    Ljung-Box test

data:  Residuals from ARIMA(1,0,0)(0,1,1)[7]
Q* = 181.25, df = 12, p-value < 2.2e-16

Model df: 2.   Total lags used: 14
```

Clearly not ideal.  Not only is the `ACF` pretty terrible looking, the Box test scores are not good.

So then I tried fitting `output_ts` simply using `auto.arima`:

```
> output_model = auto.arima(output_ts, ic = "aic")
> summary(output_model)
Series: output_ts 
ARIMA(0,0,1)(0,1,1)[7] with drift 

Coefficients:
         ma1     sma1   drift
      0.2831  -0.8924  0.0539
s.e.  0.0162   0.0124  0.0142

sigma^2 estimated as 1558:  log likelihood=-15959.89
AIC=31927.78   AICc=31927.79   BIC=31951.98

Training set error measures:
                     ME     RMSE      MAE        MPE     MAPE      MASE       ACF1
Training set 0.01322627 39.40545 29.10605 -0.6122858 5.791276 0.7795865 0.03899792
```

Which seems to indicate that `auto.arima` is uncovering the same model that we originally selected manually.  The residuals look similarly terrible:

```
> checkresiduals(output_model)

    Ljung-Box test

data:  Residuals from ARIMA(0,0,1)(0,1,1)[7] with drift
Q* = 369.05, df = 11, p-value < 2.2e-16

Model df: 3.   Total lags used: 14
```

[image: auto arima residuals]

Which leads me to hope that someone might be able to help with a few questions:

1. Is the seasonality of the daily data (period = 7) somehow clashing with the `auto.arima` restrictions on the order of ARIMA model?  According to the documentation, the maximum order checked by `auto.arima` is (5,2,5)x(2,1,2).
2. How would you suggest I go about working towards a better seasonal arima model?

Comment: Post your data to dropbox.com.  Specify the beginning date.

Comment: auto.arima (without x's) definitely clashes with day-of-the-week effects ...which is why one needs to combine both deterministic effects ( like day-of-the-week , week-of-the-month , day-of-the-month, month-of-the-year, week-of-the-year, lead and lag effects around holidays AND arima structure AND of course pulse effects.

Comment: File uploaded here: https://gofile.io/?c=g2pnfm